# ¿Como ejecutar un programa PHP y a cada tiempo determinado una otra funcion?

Tags: php

¿Como ejecuto una función a cada determinado tiempo?
Voy acceder a un WS y coger un token que debe ser renovado a cada termpo determinado durante unas busqueda que haré a través de un método. Entonces estoy intentando hacer algo para probar con el ejemplo abajo.

Mi programa debe leer un tabla y a cada 5 segundos debe ser interrumpido para ejecutar una función hasta leer toda la tabla de datos.
Ejemplo:

1 - Leyendo la tabla de datos

```
$id=0;

$sql = "SELECT id,refer_con FROM tb_aux where id > $id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

   if($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $id=$row["id"];
         $contr=$row["refer_con"];       
     }
   }
```

2 - Función

```
     $x = 1;
     while($x > 0){
       sleep(5);      
       echo ' contr: '.$contr. '-'.'x:'.$id.'--'.date('h:i:s').'<br>';
     }
```

3 - Flujo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayda

Comment: Es mejor hacerlo con un crontab que llame a tu archivo PHP cada `X` tiempo.

Comment: A.Cedano, en la verdad voy a acceder a un WS y coger un token que debe ser renovado a cada un determinado tiempo. Por eso creo que el crontab no me queda.

Comment: en `WS` quien maneja la ejecución cada X cantidad de tiempo el `Token`?? tambien te sugiero que mejores la forma en que muestras el flujo de tu programa; emplea una imagen de un power point o un tree view para entenderlo mejor...

Comment: Francisco, en esta tarea quien maneja la cantidad X de tiempo es el TOKEN, por eso és que para cada requisicion se hace verificar se el token está válido aun.Se no está se hace una busqueda de un nuevo token.